# Finding length of adjacent datagaps in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

is there a way to find the maximum length of contiguous periods without data for each column? `
`df.isna().sum()` gives me the number of all nan but here in the example I am looking for a way to get for A=3 and B=2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
i = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=8, freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 5, np.nan ,np.nan, np.nan, 2, 5, np.nan], 'B' : [np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6, np.nan, 8]}, index=i)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For one Series you can make groups of consecutive NaNs using the non-NaNs as starting points. Then count them and get the max:

```
s = df['A'].isna()
s.groupby((~s).cumsum()).sum().max()
```

Output: `3`

Now do this for all columns:

```
def max_na_stretch(s):
    s = s.isna()
    return s.groupby((~s).cumsum()).sum().max()

df.apply(max_na_stretch)
```

Output:

```
A    3
B    2
dtype: int64
```